# Apache error while stopping

Tags: apache, error-handling

I tried to stop apache `apachectl stop`.  but it was showing error like:

> httpd (no pid file) not running

And when I checked `ps -ef | grep httpd`, it shows apache as running.

And then I killed the pid of running apache, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

This maybe because of some incorrect apache configurations.
please check the error_log under /var/log and check the error.

you can run `httpd -t` to check for any syntax errors in your apache configs.

Good Luck!